# What diode to use in keyboard matrix PCB?

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, diodes, circuit-design

I'm making a project where I redesign my old calculators PCB, so I could read the button presses with an arduino. The general design is done, all that's left is to decide on which diode is going to be used. I'm working in **EasyEDA**, so I added the first default diode available when I made the schematic.

I'm new to electronics, so I have no idea how to choose. It should be available in **LCSC** store so I can order my PCB with the diodes already soldered.

What parameters should I look out for? How can I find the right diode for my project?

*The default diode offered by EasyEDA:* https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Diodes-General-Purpose_Foshan-Blue-Rocket-Elec-1N4007W_C328592.html

*My design:*

[image]

Comment: BAS16 (2 pin version or chage to SOT23), 1N4148 (SMD equivalent). Don't use 1N400x types because if you have a fast scan rate it might cause problems.

Comment: I would second the SOT23 as they are *far* more widely available than many two contact devices.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys!

Comment: As others have said some kind of IN4148 or similar part - go to LCSC an pick their cheapest switching diode.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [LL4148](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810311713_ON-Semiconductor-LL4148_C84135.pdf), the MELF version of the 1N4148, which is very common in Asia. LCSC lists 15 or 20 different manufacturers and types. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: MELF can be tricky for hand assembly, but  I can see than land pattern mitigating their tendency for undesired mobility.

Comment: @Jasen Solder paste holds them in place nicely. If there is no stencil (gadzooks!) you solder one side first then the other.